# Allowing two devices to see each other on Android using wifi interface?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

Is it at all possible to get 2 Android handsets to see each other using the wireless interface? I'm not talking full-blown access-point mode. It would be cool if both devices could be actively looking for networks / devices whilst at the same time being 'discoverable' to other devices.

Is this possible in any way?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Just to mention, Bluetooth isn't an option because of the default time-out for discoverability. I need the devices to be doing a scan and to be discoverable without any user interaction or prompts.

Comment: And just to add to this further, the wireless interfaces would never actually form a connection - they just see each-other's MAC address.

Comment: I would use a server and GPS. Have each device connect to your server and send their GPS coordinates. You can then display users within a certain radius of each other to each other. It's not exactly what you want, but the results would be fairly similar.

Comment: # Wi-Fi Direct
I know this is an old question, but now there is a technology called [Wi-Fi Direct](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want peer-to-peer ad-hoc networking which is not currently supported in Android. See [Can Android do peer-to-peer ad-hoc networking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932150/can-android-do-peer-to-peer-ad-hoc-networking) and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82

If both devices have NFC chips and are really close (few cm) then doing the discovery with NFC might be an option for you.

Comment: Actually neither Marting nor me are looking for a full blown ad-hoc connection, but much more something like bluetooth discoverabilty. 
As Martin said it is currently unusable because of the time-limit in android. However there is some hope, because the 300sec limit is lifted in honeycomb according to the issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6348
Let's see if it would change on the mobile versions too...

Comment: Irrelevant answer. Wifi peer to peer is not supported in Android, bluetooth peer to peer is.