# Create an access point without internet connection for android devices

Tags: android

Is it possible to create programmatically an access point without to be connected to internet connection for android OS ?

Comment: what do you mean by "access point?"

Comment: i want to create an android application, which others peers can connect to, but without internet connection.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932150/can-android-do-peer-to-peer-ad-hoc-networking

Comment: but, in ad hoc networks, there is no access points, and what i want to do is something like a Software Access Point.