# android wifi peer to peer

Tags: java, android, api, version

I found that from the [Android website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) they told me the current API 
that enable developers to do some **programming** for **Wifi Peer to Peer 
is ONLY in Android 4.0** (API level 14).

Is it true? I mean can I only use the Earlier version of Android instead of Android 4.0 to do the Wifi Peer to Peer 
programming? Can I use android 2.3 or earlier for doing the Wifi Peer2Peer Access?

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly stated at developer sight that Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) allows Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later devices not prior.
Please visit
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

you can use 4.0 or later versions for the Wifi Peer to Peer programming where the Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) APIs allow applications to connect to nearby devices without needing to connect to a network or hotspot.Wi-Fi P2P allows your application to quickly find and interact with nearby devices, at a range beyond the capabilities of Bluetooth. it is at 4.0 and later not prior.

Comment: so if you said, "4.0 and later not prior". THat means I cant use my "2.3" for this wifi peer2peer right?

Comment: yes you can not as stated in doc!!, if the answer is feasible to you please accept it that it will also be helpful to others

Comment: but @Jitesh, I found from the another library 
it said they can do it while using android 2.3 look at here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932150/can-android-do-peer-to-peer-ad-hoc-networking

Comment: if there is a lib than have try with that but it is an old post of 2009...please check