# RPI as a central server for co-located android devices

Tags: android, networking, raspberry-pi

I would like to use a raspberry pi as a central server for an application I'm building. Basically, I want the raspberry Pi to act as a server which can be used by co-located mobile devices to communicate with each other. I'm trying to build a local access network, and there is no need for an Internet connection. I am going to build an application on Android to interface with the server.

I have considered using an ad-hoc network, however, I have found through the following (among others):

1. [Can
   Android do peer-to-peer ad-hoc networking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932150/can-android-do-peer-to-peer-ad-hoc-networking)
2. [xda-developers
   thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1718053)

that Android does not play nicely with ad-hoc networks unless rooted. I am not in a position to root the cellphones, so what else could one do in this instance?

What is a replacement for an ad-hoc network that is compatible with android?

Comment: Why not use a standard Wifi network. You could make the Raspberry Pi the access point, or just use a cheap wireless router.

Comment: Yes, as Jonathon suggests, make the pi function as an access point (you will need a USB dongle which supports that) or use a router with a decent amount of memory capable of running an open firmware instead.  Details of configuring the pi/router would be found on other sites, or belong on the pi or networking stack exchange sites.  Specific programming questions in the development of your server itself or the client Android app could belong here.

Comment: using the Raspberry Pi as an access point implies that there's an existing network already, does it not? (I simply want to create a local area network for mobile devices from scratch, one that is disconnected from the Internet) .Also, I want to explore my options a bit here, can android connect to a Infrastructure WLAN network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an Access Point, as suggested by @Jonathon Reinhart. Here's a tutorial on how to do that http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot